# ERROR en columna id no encontrada en tabla de API REST laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Estoy creando un API rest con Laravel 5.8

Y he definido mi tabla con el campo "producto_id" campo en lugar de "id" y al realizar las pruebas con update o delete obtengo este error

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found:
>   1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' (SQL:
>   select * from `productos` where `id` = 2 limit 1) in file

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo el modelo Producto

[image: Codigo del modelo]

Tengo el controlador con las funciones sin definir solamente para realizar pruebas

[image: Controlardor sin implementar]

Tengo la definicion de la migracion

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando cambio el campo a id si funciona el update, pero quiero saber como hago para poder usar el nombre producto_id en lugar de id y evitar ese error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Laravel por defecto va a buscar una columna llamada `id` a la cual va a identificar como llave primaria.

Lo anterior lo puedes comprobar al ir a la siguiente ruta:

> miproyecto\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent

Y revisar las propiedades que tiene el archivo clase que se llama `Model.php`

- En caso de que el nombre sea distinto al pedido en la convención, entonces en tu modelo debes declarar la siguiente propiedad:

Dentro de tu modelo `Producto.php` va la siguiente propiedad:

```
protected $primaryKey = 'producto_id';
```

**Referencia**

- [Convenciones en los modelos de Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions)

Comment: Muchas gracias!